# Docker on Cloud hosting

Tags: docker, cloud, hosting

Recently i created a linode account and installed docker in ubuntu 14.04LTS
i installed an image, and ran a container, everything is working properly at the moment.

I wanted to do a `scp` from my local machine to linode directory and i did successfully like so.

```
scp file.txt root@ip:/path/to/directory
```

only my problem started when i realized docker container has its own `root@hostname:/path/to/directory` within the linode `root@ip:/`and that i did not know how to do a `scp` from my local machine directly to the container path, simply because i do not know the syntax and i'm not very experienced with the process.

I looked around asked Linode for support but there was very little they could assist me with.

I decided to test some of my theories such as: instead of `scp` directly to the docker container i would `scp` to linode `scp file.txt root@ip:/home` and from there i would do a `docker cp file.txt <container-name>:/path/to/directory` after i click enter, i get no response neither error nor success.

i'm a beginner on all of this so what am i missing? what am i not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `docker cp` aproach is right. And in fact it doesn't return any response. Your can check if the file was indeed copied using a `docker exec containerid bash`.

There is another way more complicated and not recommended. If you install openssh in your container and open another port lets say `-p 2222:22` you can scp directly to the container.

Of course you can do it via the docker way. Declaring a volume, linking your host directory to your container directory: `-v /path/to/directory:/path/to/directory`. Then your scp to your host will work.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for responding
I'm interested in knowing more about declaring a volume and linking my host directory with my container directory.

I'm doing some search to get more information on it.

As for the docker cp, after i do it i check my container but nothing is copied into it.

this are the steps i take.
local machine -->scp file.txt--> host
then after file is inside my host
Host -->docker cp file.txt--> container.

but It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just a little feedback, i did some research on what you suggested i'm happy to say that i succeeded in creating a shared volume between host and container.

Now i can scp from local machine to host - shared directory.

Comment: Excellent. Do you think that this could be the right answer to your question?